# IntelliJ Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I tried to run my spring boot based project in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition i get a mysterious exception on Windows 10

```
JVMJ9TI064E Agent initialization function Agent_OnLoad failed for library instrument, return code -1
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Users\Rényi\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\193.7288.26\lib\idea_rt.jar
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti29(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
```

Thing I already tried, and still get the same result:

- Reinstall multiple version of IntelliJ
- Manually deleted all the leftover files and dirs after uninstall and re install the IDE

I have tried the following versions:

- 2020.1.3
- 2019.3.5
- 2019.2.4

I got exactly the same exception every time mentioned above. For installing jetbrains products i use jetbrains toolbox on windows 10 and I have `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b04)` installed.

I tried to find solution for this problem but i didnt got solution which is relevant for the IntelliJ.

Comment: is your file in the right place? Try defining the correct path. See: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/troubleshooting/errors-starting-java-app-server

Comment: Do you run it on WebSphere?

Comment: @Paul yes, the file is there on the correct path.

Comment: @y.bedrov no, i dont run it on WebSpehere

Comment: How do you run your application? Do you face the same issue with new sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov yes, I had the same issue with a new sample project. I use built-in spring boot to run my applications. when I try to run with Gradle from the console my application starts

Comment: Probably issue is caused by unicode symbol in path "Rényi"

Comment: @y.bedrov It's worked before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
I updated my adoptOpenJDK from 8.0.212.04 to 8.0.262.10.